# How to implement this view for iPhone

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview

[image]

The view I expected is like this image

The main view contains three parts: one label, one webview and one tableview. But the difficulty is their size are not fixed. I hope the webView can auto strech height according its content; the tableView's is similar to webView and its height should be decided by its content.

If webView's height is bigger than screen's height, I want to scroll the whole view not the webView.

I tried many ways but can't get the expected  result.

Comment: So tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Try to put all your component into UIScrollView..and place the scroll view in your UIView..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using UITableView  add your all component on UITableView cell by using cell.contentView and add table on your UIView.